# Best way to do this animation in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, animation, windows-phone-7

I'm building a Windows Phone 7 app in Silverlight.

I have a list of content in a `ListBox`. When the user presses a button, "Remove" icons should appear next to each item in the list. Ideally, the list items would slide over, and the icons would be animated in.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this is. I'm unfamiliar with animation in Silverlight. One approach: make a data template for the ListBox that includes the icon and the actual content. If the user hits the button, toggle the visibility of the icon. Attach event handlers to the icon being tapped. (I'm not sure how to work animation into this.)

Or is there another way to make this work?

**Update**: Ok, I have a nice animation where the content slides out and back. However, I'd like to add an icon for each item in the list. How can I do this?

```
<VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
            <ic:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditingStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Editing">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="60" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="pivotItem" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NotEditing">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="pivotItem" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Also, right now this is hardcoded to be a specific control. How can I change it to be the `pivotItem` the user is currently viewing?

Comment: Do you have Expression Blend for windows phone?  Blend makes creating animations fairly easy.

Comment: I do indeed have Expression Blend.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is not using Silverlight 4 (mentioned in the title of your question), but Silverlight 3 with some phone specific additions/exclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "canonical" case for `VisualStates` - just create one state with the icon open and one with the icon closed, and switch between them. Animations between states can be done really easily. I'd recommend you to use Blend for WP7 (free) and check this video as a starting point:

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee426922.aspx

**Edit:**

For part 2 of your question, simply add the icon to the `ItemTemplate` and make it slide from outside and/or grow (changing width/height) with the VS animation.

You should add the `VisualStates` to the item template in the `ListBox`; by doing that you'll be able to reference the correct instance of the control and icon in the VS animation.

Comment: Can you show some sample XAML for how to animate the item template with the visual states?

Answer (score 1):

Use storyboards in your listbox control, if you do not have an idea try using expression blend for windows phone 7 then just add a key frame just like Adobe flash.